# How to convert excel data to json in python?

Tags: python, json

My data is below

| food ID | name | ingredients | ingredient ID | amount | unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rice | red | R1 | 10 | g |
| 1 | soup | blue | B1 | 20 | g |
| 1 | soup | yellow | Y1 | 30 | g |

and I want to convert it like this

```
{
  'data': [
    {
      'name': 'rice',
      'ingredients': [
        {
          'name': 'red',
          'ingredient_id':'R1',
          'amount': 10,
          'unit': 'g',
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      'name': 'soup',
      'ingredients': [
        {
          'name': 'blue',
          'ingredient_id':'B1',
          'amount': 20,
          'unit': 'g',
        },
        {
          'name': 'yellow',
          'ingredient_id':'Y1',
          'amount': 30,
          'unit': 'g',
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I do it? Do I need to use the same library as pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can modify your data by using custom code function inside python.

For your required format you need to use this code for format your data into json.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 'rice', 'red', 'R1', 10, 'g'],
    [1, 'soup', 'blue', 'B1', 20, 'g'],
    [1, 'soup', 'yellow', 'Y1', 30, 'g'],
    [1, 'apple', 'yellow', 'Y1', 30, 'g']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['food ID', 'name', 'ingredients', 'ingredient ID', 'amount', 'unit'])

def convert_data_group(group):
    ingredients = [{'name': row['ingredients'], 'ingredient_id': row['ingredient ID'], 'amount': row['amount'], 'unit': row['unit']} for _, row in group.iterrows()]
    return {'name': group.iloc[0]['name'], 'ingredients': ingredients}

unique_names = df['name'].unique().tolist()
result = []
for name in unique_names:
    group = df[df['name'] == name]
    result.append(convert_data_group(group))

final_result = {'datas': result}
print(final_result)
```

**Your final result will be:**

```
{'datas': [{'name': 'rice', 'ingredients': [{'name': 'red', 'ingredient_id': 'R1', 'amount': 10, 'unit': 'g'}]}, {'name': 'soup', 'ingredients': [{'name': 'blue', 'ingredient_id': 'B1', 'amount': 20, 'unit': 'g'}, {'name': 'yellow', 'ingredient_id': 'Y1', 'amount': 30, 'unit': 'g'}]}, {'name': 'apple', 'ingredients': [{'name': 'yellow', 'ingredient_id': 'Y1', 'amount': 30, 'unit': 'g'}]}]}
```

[image]

Comment: sir, how can I do sort data not rice , soup but soup, rice? I have many data, so when I adjust your solution, ingredient data order is twisted.

Comment: Sorry I can not understand your question. Explain what you want to from result.

Comment: If you look at the order of the text, it is printed in order of rice and soup, but if you assume that apple was added last in the table I have, I executed your code. Then, json data (name) is not output in the order of rice, soup, and apple, but in the order of apple, rice, and soup (abc). Do you understand? I'm sorry for my lack of explanation.

Comment: Yes. This code will give you result in asc order like apple, rice and soup.

Comment: Oh, I got it. then.. Is there any way "not to apply" ascending order? In other words, is there any way to print it out in the order shown in the table?

Comment: and why you use _ in for _, row in group.iterrows()? Is there any special reason?

Comment: add a new code for get result without asc order. And for _,row is iteration for your data object

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. It very helpful. I have to study hard about pandas and python. Good luck!!

Comment: I'm sorry for that your new answer is doesn't work that The result of the new code is different from the first code. There are two soups!

Comment: You can check by change the data of soup to apple and check.

Comment: I tested it, but the results are different. The first code has two recipes under soup, but the second code has the order I want, but the large category called soup is printed twice. sorry for my ignorance...

Comment: Code edited and now you will get your required output

Comment: Thank you sir. It is what I wanted. I'm sorry to bother you.